# 複数スレッドからファイルアクセスする場合の、適切なロック方法

Tags: linux, c

C言語で複数スレッドからファイルアクセスする場合、ロックする関数についてご教示ください。

下記のようなプログラムを作成しています。

・スレッド(1)は、ファイルに対してライトします。
・スレッド(2)は、スレッド(1)によってライトされたファイルに対してリードします。
・必ずしもスレッド(1)(2)は同じファイルにアクセスするわけではなく、スレッドごとにfopen()します。
・タイミングによってスレッド(1)(2)は同じファイルにアクセスします。

・（不測の自体でロックをとったままスレッドが落ちてしまった場合、他方のスレッド側ロックを強制解除して処理は継続させたいです（別途エラーメッセージはログに出力します）。

flock(fd,LOCK_EX)をつかってロックを取る方針で検討していたのですが、
「flock()はファイル記述子ごとにロックするので、
fopen()を別々に行っていては正しくロックできないのでは？」
との指摘を受けて、ロックのとり方を再検討している最中です。

Comment: この記事 [File locking in Linux](https://gavv.github.io/blog/file-locks/) の、`POSIX record locks (fcntl)` が参考になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。`fcntl()`について、スグに理解できなかった(ファイルディスクリプタでなくファイル単位でロックしたいって話だったのに、ファイルディスクリプタが引数でいいんだっけ？)ので、詳しい回答聞けるかとおもって新規に質問をした次第です。sayuriさんやmetropolisさんのおっしゃる通り`fcntl()`を使う方向で検討します。

Comment: シングルプロセス・プロセス内部での排他が前提にありますか？ そうであれば質問文に明記してください。マルチプロセスでは状況が全く異なります。

Comment: 排他を取るのはシングルプロセスです。プロセス監視して落ちたときにプロセス再起動させる監視プロセスもつくってましたが、本来はsystemdのRestart = always を利用すべきだったと思ってます。

Comment: オフトピック気味ですが：一般的に「不測の事態でスレッドが落ちた」場合の処理継続・縮退運用・復旧は不可能かと思います。マルチスレッドプログラムではメモリ空間を始めあらゆるリソースが密結合となりますから、任意のタイミングで他スレッドが死んでしまうと、それ以降に信頼性のある処理を行うことが事実上できません。障害耐性を重視するなら、マルチプロセスアプリケーション（疎結合）として設計し直すべきかと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linuxではあまり役に立たないかもしれませんが

C11で導入された[`fopen_s()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen)を使用すると排他オープンすることができます。ファイルシステムレベルでの排他なので別プロセス・別スレッドだけでなく同一スレッドであってもクローズするまでは再オープンすることができなくなります。

ただし、先行するファイル使用者がいつ完了するのか？という問題があります。完了待ちをすることを考えるとuser20098さんの提案されている`pthread_mutex_lock`などの排他・同期が適切に感じます。

---

> もスレッド(1)(2)は同じファイルにアクセスするわけではないので、mutexだと若干ロッ‌​ク範囲がおおきくなります。

ファイル毎にmutexを作成するまでです。ファイル名・mutexのペアを構造体で用意し、スレッド間で共有することになるでしょうか。
というように適切な設計を行っていくと

> スレッド毎にfopen()して、できればスレッド間でファイルディスクリプタの受け渡しはしたくな‌​いです。

などとは言っていられないです。

---

> 排他を取るのはシングルプロセスです。

とのことですが、ファイルを書き込むのも読み込むのも単一プロセス内ということでしたら、そもそもファイルを介さず、プロセス内スレッド間でメモリを共有すればいいのではと思います。

Comment: @sayuriさん 回答ありがとうございます。`fopen_s()`を使えば排他はできるのですがそれはそれで制約があり難しいのですね。私のレベルでは難しい話になってきました。sayuriさんが前回の質問で指摘していただいた「スレッドが不測の事態で落ちる様な‌​状態なのに、処理を継続するのはいいのか」という方向で関係者に話してみます。

Comment: @yuuta624 さん、追記しました。質問の前提を崩してしまいますが、そもそもファイルを介する意味があまりなさそうに感じました。

Answer (score 2):

[前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/33851/)の回答で sayuri さんが言いたかったのは、ロックする時と解除する時とで
`fp` (というか file descriptor) が違う点が問題、ということだと思います。

以下のように `flock()` でも問題ないと思います。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 2

static FILE *fp0;

static void *test0(void *parm)
{
    int n = *(int *) parm;

    if ((fp0 = fopen("test.txt", "a+")) == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (flock(fileno(fp0), LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) != 0) {
        perror("flock");
        exit(1);
    }

    return NULL;
}

static void *test1(void *parm)
{
    int n = *(int *) parm;
    FILE *fp;

    if (flock(fileno(fp0), LOCK_UN | LOCK_NB) != 0) {
        perror("flock");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((fp = fopen("test.txt", "a+")) == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (flock(fileno(fp), LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB) != 0) {
        perror("flock");
        exit(1);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thr[N];
    pthread_attr_t attr[N];
    int n[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        n[i] = i;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr[0]);
    pthread_create(&thr[0], &attr[0], test0, &n[0]);
    sleep(1);
    pthread_attr_init(&attr[1]);
    pthread_create(&thr[1], &attr[1], test1, &n[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        void *r;
        pthread_join(thr[i], &r);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`test0()` 側スレッドで `fopen()` した `fp0` を、`test1()` 側スレッドに渡す必要があります。
この `fp0` を放置すると、何度もスレッドが落ちた場合に `fclose()` されない `FILE *` がどんどん残っていってしまいます。従って強制解除と同時に `fclose()` も必要になるでしょうから、どのみち `test1()` 側スレッドに渡す必要はあるので、この点は問題にはならないと思っています。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。スレッド毎に`fopen()`して、できればスレッド間でファイルディスクリプタの受け渡しはしたくないです。

Comment: @yuuta624  `fp` のリークは問題ないのです?

Comment: @masmさん　スレッドが不測の事態でおちる状態を想定していたので、リークは諦めてました。fpだけでなくその他のスレッドが確保していたものもリークします。元の質問の回答でsayuriさんもご指摘していた通り「スレッドが不測の事態で落ちる様な状態なのに、処理を継続するのはいいのか」という話ですね。そもそもスレッドが落ちないように設計、コーディングするつもりですが、スレッドが落ちたこと検知したら、プロセス再起動させたほうがよいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

同一プロセス内のスレッド間のファイル読み書きの排他制御であれば、`pthread_mutex_lock()`で制御するほうが簡易かと思います。
(と言うか、同一プロセス(PID)内ではスレッド間で`fcntl()`でのファイルロックはできないと思われます)

```
/*
 * コード例(エラー判定は省略)
 */
/* スレッド間で共有する排他制御変数 */
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZE;

/*
 * スレッド1
 */
void* thread1(void* arg) {
    /*
     * 中略
     */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    FILE* fp = fopen("file", "r");
    /*
     * ファイル操作(読み込み)
     */
    fclose(fp);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    /*
     * 以下、略
     */
}
/*
 * スレッド2
 */
void* thread2(void* arg) {
    /*
     * 中略
     */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    FILE* fp = fopen("file", "w+");
    /*
     * ファイル操作(書き込み)
     */
    fclose(fp);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    /*
     * 以下、略
     */
}
```

なお、本論から外れますが、スレッドが異常終了したことを考慮に入れるのであれば、スレッドの生死や排他変数の状態監視を行う別スレッドが必要になってくると思います。
複雑な処理の部類と思いますので、動作条件を見直した方がよいかと思います。

Comment: 'fcntl()'はスレッド間はロックできないですね。上手く行かないので、アドバイザリードロックにたいする理解不足なのかと思っていました。

Comment: mutexについてですが必ずしもスレッド(1)(2)は同じファイルにアクセスするわけではないので、mutexだと若干ロック範囲がおおきくなります。できればファイル単位でロックを取りたいです。また本論とハズれる方についてスレッド監視する別スレッドは作っていました。スレッドが落ちるような状態で動作継続すべきかも含め、動作条件は見直そうと思います。アドバイスありがとうございました。

Comment: @yuuta624 すみません、スレッド間でのロックは `Open file description locks` を使う必要があります。質問のコメント欄で紹介した記事にも記述がありますが、`fcntl()` で `F_SETLKW` の代わりに `F_OFD_SETLKW` を使います。ただ、OFD は Linux kernel 特有の機能になりますけれども。

Answer (score 1):

参考までに、以下は [Open file description locks](https://gavv.github.io/blog/file-locks/#open-file-description-locks-fcntl) を使ったサンプルコードです。

リンク先に記載がある通り、`POSIX record locks` との違いは以下で、

> The only difference is in fcntl command names:
>
> ```
> F_OFD_SETLK instead of F_SETLK
> F_OFD_SETLKW instead of F_SETLKW
> F_OFD_GETLK instead of F_GETLK
> ```

Linux kernel 3.15 以上でのみ利用可能です。

※ `POSIX record locks` である `fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, ...)` や `fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, ...)` をコメントアウトしていますが、こちらを使うと出力ファイル(`/tmp/output.dat`)の中身は期待通りになりません(部分的に上書きされるなど)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define OUTPUT "/tmp/output.dat"

void *write_thread(void *id){
  long tid = (long)id;
  struct flock lock = {
    .l_whence = SEEK_SET,
    .l_start = 0,
    .l_len = 0,   // Lock whole file
  };

  int fd = open(OUTPUT, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);

  lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
  fcntl(fd, F_OFD_SETLKW, &lock);
  //fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &lock);

  lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);

  int len; char buf[256];
  for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    len = sprintf(buf, "tid=%ld, fd=%d, i=%d\n", tid, fd, i);
    write(fd, buf, len);
  }
  fsync(fd);

  lock.l_type = F_UNLCK;
  fcntl(fd, F_OFD_SETLK, &lock);
  //fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &lock);
  close(fd);

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
  int num_threads = 3;
  pthread_t threads[num_threads];

  truncate(OUTPUT, 0);
  for (int i=0;i<num_threads;i++) {
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, write_thread, (void *)i);
  }

  for (int i=0;i<num_threads;i++) {
   pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。カーネルはLinux kernel 3.15 以上でしたが”F_OFD_SETLK”が定義されていないとコンパイルエラーになりました。コンパイ時のインクルードパスの指定が違っているのだと思っているのですが、調査が止まっています。

Comment: こちらの環境は、`Ubuntu Linux 17.04/Linux kernel 4.10/gcc 7.0.1` で、`F_OFD_*` は `/usr/include/bits/fcntl-linux.h` で定義されています。`#ifdef __USE_GNU` となっているので、上記のサンプルコードの様に `#define _GNU_SOURCE` を付ける必要があります。